# Странное поведение mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Мой первый вопрос:
Двигая мышкой по тексту внутри элемента (текст помещен в отдельный div) срабатывает с очень быстрым повторением mouseenter, а нужно, чтобы срабатывал только один раз, при входе в блок square без реакции на дочерние элемент. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код был таков:

```
$('.square').mouseover(function (e){

        var color = colorGenerator();
        (this).style.backgroundColor=color;
        $(this).children('.text').remove();
        $('<div>').addClass('text').appendTo(this).text(color);


});
```

Мне посоветовали добавить это:

```
$('.square').mouseenter(function (e){
  if(!$(e.target).is('.text')){
   // тут код, который должен быть выполнен единожды
 }
}
```

Первую проблему это решило, но теперь цвет определяется только один раз и при повторном наведении не меняется. Как сделать, чтобы цвет менялся, но условие оставалось? Почему код в теле условия выполняется только один раз?

Answer (score 2):

Событий не 2, а 4. Два из них срабатывают на дочерние элементы, а два - нет.

Однако, подписываясь на событие, ты также подписываешься на всплытие событий от вложенных элементов. Чтобы обрабатывать только на конкретном элементе, надо проверять `event.target`.

```js
$("section").on('mouseenter mouseleave mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
  if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
    console.log(event.type)
  }
})
```

```css
section, div {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section><div></div></section>
```

А ещё в jQuery есть функция hover для подписки:

```js
$("section").hover(function (event) {
  console.log("+")
}, function (event) {
  console.log("-")
})
```

```css
section, div {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section><div></div></section>
```